# Filter queryset with same DateTime fields

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-queryset

I'm trying to filter a queryset with the same DateTime fields:

```py
objects = Obj.objects.filter(start_date_time=F('end_date_time'))
objects
<QuerySet []>
```

models.py:

```py
start_date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=now, blank=True)
end_date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=now, blank=True)
```

If I remove microseconds, then the fields are equal:

```py
obj = Obj.objects.filter(id='id').first()
obj.start_date_time
datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 10, 9, 24, 29, 326238, tzinfo=<UTC>)
obj.end_date_time
datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 10, 9, 24, 29, 326241, tzinfo=<UTC>)
obj.start_date_time == obj.end_date_time
False
obj.start_date_time.replace(microsecond=0) == obj.end_date_time.replace(microsecond=0)
True
```

How to make a request to the database correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Trunc`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/database-functions/#trunc) function to truncate the milisecond information and filter like this:

```
objects = Obj.objects.annotate(truc_start_date_time=Trunc('start_datetime', 'second', output_field=DateTimeField()), trunc_end_date_time==Trunc('endt_datetime', 'second', output_field=DateTimeField())).filter(trunc_start_date=F('trunc_end_date'))
```

Another alternative is to filter using all segments of the date time object (ie [date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#date), [hour](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#hour), [minute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#minute), [second](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#second))

```
objects = Obj.objects.filter(start_date_time_day__date = F('end_datetime__date'), start_date_time_day__hour =  F('end_datetime__hour'), start_date_time_day__minute =  F('end_datetime__minute'), start_date_time_day__second =  F('end_datetime__second'))
```

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more efficient way is to truncate with [**`.alias(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#alias) and then filter directly, this will prevent that the values end up in the `SELECT` clause. We can also work with [**`TruncSecond`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncSecond)

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncSecond

Obj.objects.alias(trunc_start_date_time=TruncSecond('start_date_time')).filter(
    trunc_start_date_time=TruncSecond('end_date_time')
)
```